# Installing python packages doesn't work on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pycharm, package

I use a Macbook pro with **10.15.1 Catalina**. I run Python 3.5 and use **Pycharm** as my IDE.

I had some experience with **Pycharm** and python on my windows PC a year ago and wanted to work on some old projects, but I have no idea what to do.

I tried to install different packages on my Mac, but it doesn't work.
I used:
    pip install 
it didn't work,

```
pip3 install <package name>
```

it at least tried to install something, but only said, that the versions are not satisfying...,

```
brew install <pacakge name>
```

that said, it would work, but as I tried to use it, **Pycharm** (the IDE I use) wanted to install it again. Sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not and now it won't work at all...
And every time I want to use pyqt5 in a different project **Pycharm** wants to install it again and can't find it...

I do not know what to do and looked around to find someone with the same problem, but have no idea what the solution to my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had great luck installing python libraries to Mac. I've gone through each of the versions installed, tried all sort of [python management strategies](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac). In the end the easiest thing for me to do was to grab the library and drag it into whatever projects folder I'm working in.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't quiet where the packages/ libraries are and for some, I don't even get them installed so I don't even have the library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it all. It goes like this:
You go on google an search for the package you want to install. You click the link, that leads you to the pypi site.
On there you have on the left side die category download and from there you get the .tar file.
You open that file and then open a terminal in the new folder. And the final step now is, to pray that the "setup.py" file is in there.
Enter the following command into the terminal:
    `python3 setup.py install`
(For me it is python3 for you it could be just python)
It will give you an error message, but it works just fine in pycharm...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried install with `--user` flag?

```
pip install --user requests
```

Or using `virtualenv`?

Comment: No but I will the first one the next time when I have to install a new package! Thank you for your help